# Check if there are 3 consecutive values in an array which are above some threshold

Tags: python, numpy

Say I have a np.array like this:

```
a = [1, 3, 4, 5, 60, 43, 53, 4, 46, 54, 56, 78]
```

Is there a quick method to get the indices of all locations where 3 consecutive numbers are all above some threshold? That is, for some threshold `th`, get all `x` where this holds:

```
a[x]>th and a[x+1]>th and a[x+2]>th
```

Example: for threshold 40 and the list given above, x should be `[4,8,9]`.

Many thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "quick method"? Easy to type without a lot of fuz, or highly optimized and supper fast?

Answer (score 8):

**Approach #1**

Use `convolution` on the mask of boolean array obtained after comparison -

```
In [40]: a # input array
Out[40]: array([ 1,  3,  4,  5, 60, 43, 53,  4, 46, 54, 56, 78])

In [42]: N = 3 # compare N consecutive numbers

In [44]: T = 40 # threshold for comparison

In [45]: np.flatnonzero(np.convolve(a>T, np.ones(N, dtype=int),'valid')>=N)
Out[45]: array([4, 8, 9])
```

**Approach #2**

Use `binary_erosion` -

```
In [77]: from scipy.ndimage.morphology import binary_erosion

In [31]: np.flatnonzero(binary_erosion(a>T,np.ones(N, dtype=int), origin=-(N//2)))
Out[31]: array([4, 8, 9])
```

**Approach #3 (Specific case) : Small numbers of consecutive numbers check**

For checking such a small number of consecutive numbers (three in this case), we can also `slicing` on the compared mask for better performance -

```
m = a>T
out = np.flatnonzero(m[:-2] & m[1:-1] & m[2:])
```

#### Benchmarking

Timings on `100000` repeated/tiled array from given sample -

```
In [78]: a
Out[78]: array([ 1,  3,  4,  5, 60, 43, 53,  4, 46, 54, 56, 78])

In [79]: a = np.tile(a,100000)

In [80]: N = 3

In [81]: T = 40

# Approach #3
In [82]: %%timeit
    ...: m = a>T
    ...: out = np.flatnonzero(m[:-2] & m[1:-1] & m[2:])
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.83 ms per loop

# Approach #1
In [83]: %timeit np.flatnonzero(np.convolve(a>T, np.ones(N, dtype=int),'valid')>=N)
100 loops, best of 3: 10.9 ms per loop

# Approach #2    
In [84]: %timeit np.flatnonzero(binary_erosion(a>T,np.ones(N, dtype=int), origin=-(N//2)))
100 loops, best of 3: 11.7 ms per loop
```

Comment: Just wondering if it works for other than 3 consecutive numbers?

Comment: right, I missed it. IIRC, binary_erision also accepts a mask, so it can be extended to the arbitrary sequence as well?

Comment: @taras Yup! Edited.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
th=40
results = [ x for x in range( len( array ) -2 )  if(array[x:x+3].min() > th) ]
```

which is a list comprehension for

```
th=40
results = []
for x in range( len( array ) -2 ):
    if( array[x:x+3].min() > th ):
        results.append( x )
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach, using `numpy.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided`:

```
in [59]: import numpy as np

In [60]: from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import as_strided
```

Define the input data:

```
In [61]: a = np.array([ 1,  3,  4,  5, 60, 43, 53,  4, 46, 54, 56, 78])

In [62]: N = 3

In [63]: threshold = 40
```

Compute the result; `q` is the boolean mask for the "big" values.

```
In [64]: q = a > threshold

In [65]: result = np.all(as_strided(q, shape=(len(q)-N+1, N), strides=(q.strides[0], q.strides[0])), axis=1).nonzero()[0]

In [66]: result
Out[66]: array([4, 8, 9])
```

Do it again with `N = 4`:

```
In [67]: N = 4

In [68]: result = np.all(as_strided(q, shape=(len(q)-N+1, N), strides=(q.strides[0], q.strides[0])), axis=1).nonzero()[0]

In [69]: result
Out[69]: array([8])
```