# Consecutive events below threshold

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have SPI timeseries of length 324 and values ranging from -3 to +3. I want to get the indices of places where 3 or more consecutive timesteps are more below threshold -1

I have thoroughly searched this site and elsewhere without major success e.g. [Check if there are 3 consecutive values in an array which are above some threshold](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51702622/check-if-there-are-3-consecutive-values-in-an-array-which-are-above-some-threshod) but doesnt do exactly what I want

```
Assuming this is what I want to do
th = -1 # threshold

a = [-3,4,5,-1,-2,-5,1,4,6,9,-3,-3,-1,-2,4,1,4] # my data

a[x]<th and a[x+1]<th and a[x+2]<th # find 3 or more consecutive   
time below threshold 

in this case that will be event e1=[-1,-2,-5] and e2=[-3,-3,-1,-2]

next I want to count this
counts = [len(e1),len(e2)] = [3,4]
Sum = [np.sum(e1),np.sum(e2)] = [-8, -9]
```

This is what I want to do and help will really be appreciated, 
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `np.logical_and.reduce` + `shift`, checking for consecutive rows that are below the threshold. Then a groupby to get all of the aggregations you need:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def get_grps(s, thresh=-1, Nmin=3):
    """
    Nmin : int > 0
        Min number of consecutive values below threshold.
    """
    m = np.logical_and.reduce([s.shift(-i).le(thresh) for i in range(Nmin)])
    if Nmin > 1:
        m = pd.Series(m, index=s.index).replace({False: np.NaN}).ffill(limit=Nmin-1).fillna(False)
    else:
        m = pd.Series(m, index=s.index)

    # Form consecutive groups
    gps = m.ne(m.shift(1)).cumsum().where(m)

    # Return None if no groups, else the aggregations
    if gps.isnull().all():
        return None
    else:
        return s.groupby(gps).agg([list, sum, 'size']).reset_index(drop=True)
```

---

```
get_grps(pd.Series(a))
#               list  sum  size
#0      [-1, -2, -5]   -8     3
#1  [-3, -3, -1, -2]   -9     4

get_grps(pd.Series(a), thresh=-1, Nmin=1)
#               list  sum  size
#0              [-3]   -3     1
#1      [-1, -2, -5]   -8     3
#2  [-3, -3, -1, -2]   -9     4

get_grps(pd.Series(a), thresh=-100, Nmin=1)
#None
```

Comment: please is there anyway I can apply a rolling window function to this code: I want to to this in rolling window of 60 time steps

Answer (score 2):

Here is a commented step-by-step recipe.

```
a = [-3,4,5,-1,-2,-5,1,4,6,9,-3,-3,-1,-2,4,1,4]
th = -1
a = np.array(a)

# create mask of events; find indices where mask switches
intervals = np.where(np.diff(a<=th, prepend=0, append=0))[0].reshape(-1,2)

# discard short stretches
intervals = intervals[np.subtract(*intervals.T) <= -3]

intervals
# array([[ 3,  6],
#        [10, 14]])

# get corresponding data
stretches = np.split(a, intervals.reshape(-1))[1::2]

stretches
# [array([-1, -2, -5]), array([-3, -3, -1, -2])]

# count events
-np.subtract(*intervals.T)
# array([3, 4])

# sum events
np.add.reduceat(a, intervals.reshape(-1))[::2]
# array([-8, -9])
```

Comment: Hi PAUL , how can i modify this to take 3d arrays instead?

Answer (score 2):

Since you tagged pandas:

```
s = pd.Series([-3,4,5,-1,-2,-5,1,4,6,9,-3,-3,-1,-2,4,1,4])

# thresholding
a = (s<1)

# blocks
b = (a!=a.shift()).cumsum()

# groupby
df = s[a].groupby(b).agg([list,'size','sum'])
df = df[df.size>=3]
```

Output

```
           list      size   sum
3       [-1, -2, -5]    3   -8
5   [-3, -3, -1, -2]    4   -9
```